# "No Parking" sign in the middle of the screen

Tags: multimedia

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Black area with stroked circle on the screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76410/black-area-with-stroked-circle-on-the-screen)

I've just installed Ubuntu 11.10, and an annoying *No Parking* sign doesn't stop to appear and disappear in the middle of the screen all the time, totally randomly!

It was on the live-CD during the installation, too. What does it mean? How can I disable it?

[image: screenshot of the problem]