# Black area with stroked circle on the screen

Tags: 11.10, lightdm, focus

Ubuntu 11.10 just installed from scratch + few applications from Ubuntu Software center installed, [log of installations](http://roman-ivanov.blogspot.com/2011/11/ubuntu-1110.html).

Black area with stroked circle is appear and block UI. Please look at pictures.
[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

Additionally I have a problem with focus during this area are about to appear or in the middle, selected text is blinking and some keys are ignore to type.

I had such problem on Ubuntu 10.04 + all updates(but without this area), that forced me to install new Ubuntu.
The same effect I see under Unity2D, and Gnome shell. Windows Vista in dual boot works fine.

I just want to open issue against Ubuntu, but do not understand what component is it,
Is there workaround?
Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/70727/no-parking-sign-in-the-middle-of-the-screen It is likely a keyboard hardware incompatibility issue.

Comment: This is a problem of keyboard and media keys - this sign means pressing - XF86AudioStop.
This button is constantly blinking on my Dell Vostro 1510.

Workaround is using Xubuntu desktop, button is blinking but now focus lost event and not sign.

Comment: I tried to disable this button by 'keycode 164 = NoSymbol" at ~/.Xmodmap file - does not help, button is disabled for me to press, but still blinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have read reports of the media keys not functioning correctly on the Dell Vostro 1510 under both [Ubuntu](http://forums.majorgeeks.com/showthread.php?t=229149) and [Windows](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1056679) causing the keys to blink and cause media playback issues etc.

You could try using xbindkeys to remap the keyboard to fix the problem - it is available in the software centre to download - just do a search for it.

Alternatively [here is a link to the developers website](http://www.nongnu.org/xbindkeys/).

Comment: thanks for answer, I already gave up, and switched to Fedora unfortunately, I need to continue my work. I will try on next attempt to use Ubuntu - my favorite linux.

Comment: I got the same problem on Fedora too, so looks like hardware problem, but with you answer I resolved it, Thanks a lot. Here is my [changes](http://roman-ivanov.blogspot.com/2011/11/xmodmap-and-xbindkeys-to-disable-media.html) to system. Sorry I can not make your answer as "right" not enough reputation.

Comment: Glad you were able to solve the issue and get your system working, now you just need to switch back to Ubuntu!! - by the way you don't need reputation to accept an answer, see the [FAQ here](http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask). I also recommend you have a good read through the whole section as it is really useful in understanding the site and how it works.

Comment: Problem appear again, not that severe like without this fix, problem reproduced on widows vista too, [here](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1056679) is discussion that propose workaround - unplug charge cable and work on battery only - works like a magic. [Update](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/usgen1/DriverDetails/DriverFileFormats?DriverId=R215210) for bios does not help.

Comment: Problem was reproduced in Windows and Ubuntu and Fedora ... problem completely in hardware. Solution: new laptop :)